# Calculating portfolio turnover

Tags: r, portfolio, r-portfolioanalytics

I have a portfolio that rebalances each month, and I would like to work out the  portfolio turnover in R on a annual basis.

My excel file has the date, security and weight

I know that I will have to use the portfolio.analytics package, however I am a complete novice in that and R. Any help will be very helpful!

subset of data:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VELEr.png)

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack. What kind of output do you want? What do you exactly want and what have you tried?

Comment: Hi! I am looking for a turnover percentage. I know the generic formula is (number of buys-number of sells)/(fund value). I want to know the steps on how to calculate it via R and the best way of replicating it for different portfolios

Comment: See this answer https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/55329/13571